# Spring Boot: what do these logs mean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I am booting up a Spring Boot application locally and I am seeing logs similar to the following streaming indefinitely. They are not being triggered by anything in particular, outside of the application just running.

```
DEBUG 24196 --- [trics-publisher] m.measurements.UdpInlinerSender : Measure being sent:
[*myapplicationname*].logback_events,dc=fake-dc,host=fake-dev-hostname,level=info count=2.0 1632348589924000000
```

Does anyone know what these could possibly indicate and if they are expected? I tried googling things like "UpdInlinerSender" and "trics-publisher" but I am getting empty google search results.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `UdpInlinerSender` is part of [metrics-influxdb](https://github.com/davidB/metrics-influxdb)

You should have the following dependency (or transitive dependency):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.davidb</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-influxdb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```